# ViewPager not showing second fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to show 4 fragments in one only ViewPager but when I scroll between Fragments the second fragment is not showing at all. It only shows Fragment 1,3 and 4 correctly.

I have checked a lot of other answers about stuff like this and they suggest to use

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

and seems to work but, I can't use that because I'm using androidx.

**This is my code in my MainActivity class:**

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SectionPagerAdapter sectionPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.menu_viewPager);

        sectionPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this, getFragmentList());

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(sectionPagerAdapter);
    }

    private List<Fragment> getFragmentList() {
        List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        fragmentList.add(new HomeMenuFragment(this));
        fragmentList.add(new RestaurantsListFragment(this));
        fragmentList.add(new OrdersMenuFragment(this));
        fragmentList.add(new AccountConfigurationFragment(this));
        return fragmentList;
    }
```

**And this is my Adapter class for ViewPager:**

```
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
        this.fragments=fragments;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 3:
                return "SECTION 4";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**This is the my XML file for the first Fragment (HomeMenuFragment):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:background="@color/grayLight2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



                <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        android:background="@color/grayLight2"
                        >
                        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                            android:id="@+id/banner_view_pager"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:overScrollMode="never"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/slider_dots"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

                </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/food_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />


        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**I realize that what is causing this problem is what I have in my first Fragment's XML file:**

```
CoordinatorLayout
AppBarLayout
CollapsingToolbarLayout
Toolbar
```

If I remove this elements the ViewPager displays all fragments correctly!

Any idea of what could I be doing wrong or what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `getChildFragmentManager()` method is a member of `Fragment`, and isn't available because you're in an `Activity`, not because you're using androidx. You're using the correct `FragmentManager` already. What exactly do you mean by "the second fragment is not showing at all"? Are you ending up with only three pages? Or is the second one just not displaying as you're expecting? If the latter, are you sure that second `Fragment` works on its own?

Comment: Thanks for making that clear to me. About "the second fragment is not showing at all" I do have 4 pages, the fragment it's not being displayed as I expect. And finally, yes. The fragment works on it's own because I even switch places with second and third fragment and the same problem occurs to the second place in ViewPager.

Comment: Please post the code and layout file for `RestaurantsListFragment`

Comment: While not related to the problem, please check #3 for how to initialize the adapter correctly (also see #4): https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for the clarification about Fragments, I will check your post!

Answer (score 0):

In your SectionPagerAdapter class add break in the case statements and try